# Create Ndarray with two columns in each row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I would like to create an nd array with n rows and two columns

I want to fill the values of the columns from two other lists So for example:

```
target_array = []

for i in range(9):
   target_array[i][0] = list_a[i]
   target_array[i][1] = list_b[i]
```

But this doesnt work, do you know how to do something similar?

Comment: If you want to create a numpy array via iteration, please give a better example, or an indication of a better example - this will help all users understand the use case for such an unusual construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [363]: list_a = list(range(1,10))
In [364]: list_b = list(range(9,0,-1))
```

You build a new list by appending values to it, such as:

```
In [365]: target = []
In [366]: for i in range(9):
     ...:     target.append([list_a[i],list_b[i]])
     ...:     
In [367]: target
Out[367]: [[1, 9], [2, 8], [3, 7], [4, 6], [5, 5], [6, 4], [7, 3], [8, 2], [9, 1]]
```

If you need an array, instead of a list, just create it from the list:

```
In [368]: np.array(target)
Out[368]: 
array([[1, 9],
       [2, 8],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 6],
       [5, 5],
       [6, 4],
       [7, 3],
       [8, 2],
       [9, 1]])
```

Comment: I wish OP would explain why in the world they would prefer this over a simple column_stacking operation.